# What is the most concise way of creating an associated array with all NULL values?

Tags: php, arrays

For instance, creating the following array?

```
$myArray=array(
    'a'=>null,
    'b'=>null,
    'c'=>null,
    'd'=>null,
    'e'=>null,
    'f'=>null,
    'g'=>null,
    'h'=>null
);
```

Comment: [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys) and [`range()`](http://php.net/range).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$myArray = array_fill_keys(range('a','h'), null);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/234183)

Answer (score 3):

This is what you're looking for

```
$myArray = array_fill_keys(array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'), null);
```